# pull access denied for mypostgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login' : how to name 'mypostgres'

Tags: docker

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and run next command:

docker run -d mypostgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1111 postgres -c shared_buffers=256MB -c max_connections=200

and I got following answer:

Unable to find image 'mypostgres:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for mypostgres, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.

So what is the correct name for 'mypostgres'?
Can I write here the occasional name that I want?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `postgres` instead if you want to download the image from [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres). If you want specific version you can use tags provided on the dockerhub page ie. `postgres:14.5`

What you are missing here is `--name` switch before `mypostgres` You can use `--name` switch to name your container

Full command:

```
docker run -d --name mypostgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1111 postgres -c shared_buffers=256MB -c max_connections=200
```

Comment: I got 'invalid reference format"  error

Answer (score 1):

--name before mypostgres , because docker understood that you want an image called mypostgres not a postgres images. and didn't find an official image with that name.

Comment: I got 'invalid reference format"  error